# Find the norm of $A$ where $(Af)(t)=tf(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I have the following problem that I would like to ask you about:

I have $X$ as my normed linear vector space and $B(X,X)=B(X)$ as my space of all operators $A: X \to X$, where for all $A \in B(X)$ is bounded and continuous.

I need to find the norm of $A \in B(X)$ given by $(Af)(t)=tf(t)$ $(0\leq t \leq 1)$ where
(a) $X=C[0,1]$ (b) $X=L^p(0,1)$ and $(1\leq p \leq \infty)$.

First I went by the definition of operator norm:
$$\|A\|=\sup \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \text{ and } \|x\|=1$$
so take $f \in C[0,1]$ and I went to it:
\begin{align*}
\|A\| &= \sup \frac{\|Af(t)\|}{\|f(t)\|} \\
      &= \sup \frac{\|tf(t)\|}{\|f(t)\|} \\
      &\leq \sup \frac{\|t\|\|f(t)\|}{\|f(t)\|} \\
      &=\sup \|t\|
\end{align*}
and so since $C[0,1]$ goes from 0 to 1. I guess the norm is 1? Not sure, though.

I was wondering if Im thinking about this the right way and if it is correct, moreover, I dont know what the difference from a) to b) would be in the result :/

Im stuck somewhere. 
thanks for any help

Comment: It is best not to write $\|f(t)\|$ when you mean $\|f\|$.  And to keep in mind what norm you are writing.

Comment: It is rather $|f(t)|$.

Comment: In the case of a), the sup is actually attained: take $f = 1$. For b), except for the $p = \infty$ case, try to show you can get arbitrarily close to $1$ by choosing the support of $f$ close to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) So, you already have that $\|A\|\le 1$ (because $t\in [0,1]$ so $\sup_t |t|=1$ indeed). To prove the equality, it is enough to find any function $f$ which satisfies $\|Af\|_\max=\|f\|_\max$, simplest might be to consider the constant $f(t)=1$.

(b) For $p\in (1,\infty)$, if $f\in L^p(0,1)$, then, as you stated, we similarly have 
$$(\|Af\|_p)^p = \int_0^1 t^p\,|f(t)|^p\, dt \le \int_0^1|f(t)|^p\,dt=(\|f\|_p)^p
$$
so $\|A\|\le 1$ follows in this case, too. However, now we can't find a function $f$ with $\|Af\|_p=\|f\|_p$.
On the other hand, we can approximate this limit: one way is to observe that with $f(t)=t^s$ for some $s\in\Bbb R$, we have $Af\,(t)=t^{p+s}$, yielding $(\|Af\|_p)^p= 
\displaystyle\frac1{p+s+1} $, thus
$$\left(\frac{\|Af\|_p}{\|f\|_p}\right)^p=\frac{s+1}{p+s+1}$$
which can get arbitrarily close to $1$ as $s\to+\infty$.

The case $p=\infty$ is essentially the same as (a).

Comment: Still early morning here but I belive there is a typo. With $f(t)=t^s $ we get $Af(t)=t^{s+1}$ and then the last equality becomes $\frac {ps+1 } {ps+p+1 } \to 1$. Exactly the same result though!

Comment: @MrFranzen: yes, you're right.